# I want to open Adapter class when I click the imageView but i get ActivityNotFoundException,any alternative method to do so?

Tags: java, android, adapter

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

```
    int i = v.getId();

    if (i==R.id.cars){

        Intent open_adapter_class = new Intent(this,ItemsAdapter.class);

        startActivity(open_adapter_class );
```

}

}

//this is the error I get

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

{com.dikolobe.salesagent/com.dikolobe.salesagent.ItemsAdapter}; have you declared this activity in your

AndroidManifest.xml?

I know that am getting this error because adapter is not an activity so I just want to get help on how to

open this adapter class if there is a way to do so

Comment: What does "open this adapter class" mean? Usually, an adapter is for some small piece of UI, such as a row in a list.

Answer (score 0):

From Android documentation:

> An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.
> It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity,
> broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver
> components, and Context.startService(Intent)

So, ItemsAdapter has to be an activity, (eg ...extends AppCompatActivity) so you change from one activity to another.

But what you can do is [pass an object from that class to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/15298643)

```
Intent open_adapter_class = new Intent(this,ItemsAdapter.class);
```